# Epson 2400 scanner doesn't work

Tags: 12.04, scanner, epson

My Epson Perfection 2400 Photo usb-scanner doesn't work in 12.04. The scanner is recognized, but in snapscan.conf, the backend eswf41.bin gave me an error. I have tried to start the scanner with epkowa.conf, but that did not work. What else can I try?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but with a CX4200, I hope the solution is the same. The fail is for the backend that sane uses: Epson2, you have to use "epson"

I use XSane, I don't know if other

first exec:

```
$ lsusb
```

You'll have something like this:

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 04b8:0820 Seiko Epson Corp. CX4200 MP scanner
```

If you exec xsane You'll have an error: No device, and  if you exec

```
xsane epson2:libusb:002:006
```

You'll have an error while I/O on the device

You have to exec

```
 xsane epson:libusb:002:006
```

It worked to me (^_^)
Note that 002 and 006 can be different on you computer, and it will change at the port you connect the scanner.

I hope someone tell us how to force epson insted epson2 by default in sane